# How do I compare abstract WeakTypeTag's unrepresented Generics

Tags: scala, generics, scala-macros

I need to check the type of any object and get the corresponding object.
However, T can not be resolved by passing it to a normal functional parameter.
You need to compare until all the type parameters match.

```scala
trait Wrap[T]

trait Interface
trait InterfaceA extends Interface
trait InterfaceB extends Interface

object InterfaceAImpl extends Wrap[InterfaceA] with Candidate
object InterfaceBImpl extends Wrap[InterfaceB] with Candidate

trait Mediate[T <: Interface] {
  val t: T = get[Wrap[T]]
}

object A extends Mediate[InterfaceA]
object B extends Mediate[InterfaceB]
```

```scala
def get[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Option[T]] = {
    import c.universe._

    // Find an object that mixes in a specific interface
    // Suppose that the result is [[object A]] and [[object B]]
    val detected: List[Symbol] = new CandidateExtractor[c.type](c).run[Candidate]

    // This result is
    // "InterfaceAImpl =:= Wrap[T]"
    // "InterfaceBImpl =:= Wrap[T]"
    // When called from A, it expects Wrap[InterfaceA] instead of Wrap[T]
    detected.foreach(x => println(s"${x.typeSignature} =:= ${weakTypeOf[T]}"))

    // Find objects that inherits Wrap [T] among objects that inherit a specific interface
    val r = detected.collectFirst {
      // Wrap[InterfaceA] and Wrap[T] are compared, so all false.
      case x if x.typeSignature =:= weakTypeOf[T] => x
    }

    c.Expr[Option[T]](
      q"$r"
    )
  }
```

Is there any way to compare inheritance relationships, including generics?

### For second Try

As a result, what I want to do is...

1. `object A`'s `t: T` = `InterfaceAImpl` because it inherits `Wrap[InterfaceA]`
2. `object B`'s `t: T` = `InterfaceBImpl` because it inherits `Wrap[InterfaceB]`

So `<:<(typeOf[Wrap[_])` is invalid.
Must be `<:<(Wrap[_])`
and `baseClasses.find(Wrap[_]).typeArgs.contains(T (is InterfaceA or InterfaceB))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
List(typeOf[Wrap[_]].typeSymbol, typeOf[Candidate].typeSymbol).forall(x.typeSignature.baseClasses.contains)
```

or

```
List(typeOf[Wrap[_]].typeSymbol, typeOf[Candidate].typeSymbol).forall(x.typeSignature.baseType(_) match { case _ : TypeRef => true; case NoType => false })
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it.
`x.typeSignature.typeConstructor` is `A.type` or `B.type`.
`weakTypeOf[T].typeConstructor` is `Wrap`.
So it did not match. There is an inheritance relationship, but you can not use `<: <` because it must match one or the other.

Comment: Since the example was bad, I added it.

The problem is that if you pass through a trait type parameter that can not have a context bound, the representation of T will be lost.

Comment: I'm sorry for the explanation. added a comment

Comment: @omarun Please see another update. `List(typeOf[Wrap[_]].typeSymbol, typeOf[Candidate].typeSymbol).forall(x.typeSignature.baseClasses.contains)`

Comment: Try to get TypeTag implicitly in the macro function, a warning will occur. `macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences`. Are there any specific examples for acquiring typetags?

Comment: @omarun Sounds like your macro impl signature doesn't correspond macro signature and in macro impl signature there are extra implicit parameters. https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html#generic-macros  `def map[T: c.WeakTypeTag, U: c.WeakTypeTag]
        (c: Context)
        (p: c.Expr[T => U]): c.Expr[Queryable[U]]` is `def map[T, U]
        (c: Context)
        (p: c.Expr[T => U])(implicit ttag: c.WeakTypeTag[T], ttag1: c.WeakTypeTag[T]): c.Expr[Queryable[U]]`. There shouldn't be any extra implicit parameters there.

Comment: @omarun it should be `ttag1: c.WeakTypeTag[U]`